# Cycle thru a ModelForm fields and identify FileField and ImageField

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a generic `save` method for a form.
In the save I want to iterate over the field and if the field is an instance of FileField to to some operations

```
   def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super().save(commit=False)
    for field in self.fields:
            if isinstance(field, forms.FileField) and obj:
```

This is not working because, if I check the type of field is `str`. How can I get the real model or declared type ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: the self.fields is an OrderedDictionary, so I was iteraing over the keys instead of iterating over the values:

```
for field,value in self.fields.items():
            if isinstance(value, forms.FileField) and obj:
```